# Question regarding the warning: "THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (4160x3120) to (4096x3072)."

Tags: three.js

When loading a large image, I see a warning on the console:
`"THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (4160x3120) to (4096x3072)."`

The warning is issued by three.module.js, due to exceeding the maxSize: 4096

```
cat three.module.js
...
  function resizeImage( image, needsPowerOfTwo, needsNewCanvas, maxSize ) {
...
    console.warn( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (' + image.width + 'x' + image.height + ') to (' + width + 'x' + height + ').' );
```

I don't have control over the image size (the user loads his image), and I can understand the need to place size limits.
My desktop shows the capability of Max Texture Size: 8192, and within my app I see Max Texture Size: 8192
`this._renderer.capabilities.maxTextureSize 4096`
Even if I can increase the Max Texture Size capabilities in my app e.g. from 4096 to 8192 (is it possible?),
I don't know if this is a good idea, because the app is purposed to run on different devices, which may have weaker resources.

Given the above arguments

- **should I be concerned about this warning, or just ignore it?**
- **If I should do something about it, are there suggestions on how to address this issue?**

Thanks

*My desktop shows the capability of Max Texture Size: 8192*

[image: 8192]

Comment: Just ignore it, the renderer is trying to optimize the performance  on your behalf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Tex image TEXTURE\_2D level 0 is incurring lazy initialization" on WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734645/error-tex-image-texture-2d-level-0-is-incurring-lazy-initialization-on-webgl)

Comment: The max texture size isn't up to the developer, it's up to the user's graphics card. For instance, my desktop is `8096`, my laptop is `4096` and my phone is `2048`. If you're letting the user upload their own images, the best course of action is to let the engine resize the images as it deems necessary and not worry about the warning.

Comment: @PeterO. That answer has nothing to do with Avner's question. A WebGL lazy initialization error isn't the same as a Three.js texture resizing warning.

Comment: Thanks jscastro and Marquizzo. I'll take your comments as an answer.
I'll just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this has nothing to do with max size. This is three.js trying to support users who are on WebGL1 since WebGL1 has limits on non-power-of-2 textures and how they can be used.

Looking at the code you should not get this message on WebGL2, at least in current versions of three.js

Testing

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  if (!renderer.capabilities.isWebGL2) {
    alert('your device/browser doesn't support WebGL2!');
    return;
  }

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const cubes = [];  // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/v38pV.jpg'),
  });
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);
  cubes.push(cube);  // add to our list of cubes to rotate

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

If it runs you should see no warning where as if we force WebGL1 then we get the warning message

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');

  // force WebGL1 by creating the context ourselves
  const context = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, context});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const cubes = [];  // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/v38pV.jpg'),
  });
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);
  cubes.push(cube);  // add to our list of cubes to rotate

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

You can avoid the message my setting the filtering so resizing isn't needed. In particular you need to set `minFilter` to `THREE.LinearFilter` and `wrapS` and `wrapT` to `THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping`

Example:

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  
  // force WebGL1 by creating the context ourselves
  const context = canvas.getContext('webgl', {alpha: false});
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, context});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const cubes = [];  // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  const texture = loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/v38pV.jpg');
  
  // Set the texture parameters so resizing isn't needed
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
  texture.wrapT =  THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
  
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
  });
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);
  cubes.push(cube);  // add to our list of cubes to rotate

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

You could check `renderer.capabilties.isWebGL2` and only set those texture settings if you're on WebGL1. Or you can ignore the message. three.js is just trying to make it easy to use but it's warning you that the size changed which could be important if you planned to draw on the texture or if the texture was some kind of non-image data or if you tried to compute UV coordinates from pixel coordinates based on the original image size.

Note: That is independent of the size limit. In your example your image was under the size limit. If the image is over the size limit then either (1) don't use the image, (2) let three.js scale it (3) do some other far more complicated solution like splitting the image into multiple textures and multiple planes